# Why NULL ing pointer before using it in realloc function?

Tags: c, pointers, null, allocation, realloc

If i do the following with `malloc`

```
HashTableEntry *util = malloc(sizeof(HashTableEntry) * T->capacity);
```

all works well. However if i do the following with `realloc`

```
HashTableEntry *util = realloc(util, sizeof(HashTableEntry) * T->capacity);
```

`realloc` returns `NULL`. I also get a warning by gcc, saying that i haven't initialized `util` before using it.

But, the following works perfectly well, like `malloc`

```
HashTableEntry *util = NULL;
util = realloc(util, sizeof(HashTableEntry) * T->capacity);
```

My question is why?

What i believe is happening is that, in all cases, i am creating a pointer and assigning to it the starting address of a block of heap memory i am allocating. Am i wrong somewhere?

Comment: Typical usage pattern is to `malloc` the initial block and then `realloc` if/when needed. Passing `NULL` to `realloc` is just an odd way to call `malloc`.

Comment: No, it's not odd.  Arguments to functions should always be initialized because the function might use the value of the argument.  If you don't initialize the argument, the compiler doesn't know what to do.

Comment: How did you expect it work when you passed an *uninitialized* garbage pointer to `realloc`??? How did you expecty `realloc` to know that you want it to act as `malloc`?

Comment: @user3386109: Typical usage pattern is to set the pointer to null and then use `realloc` only, taking advantage of the fact that `realloc(NULL,` is equivalent to `malloc`. This produces much more elegant and compact code without unnecessary branching and/or splitting. However, many people have no idea that they can use `realloc` uniformly in such code, for which reason they insist on splitting the first allocation into a "special case" and use `malloc`. This leads to much uglier code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, functions look at the values of their arguments and use the values to do something, so it's important to pass a specific value instead of something random or unspecified.  When you write `HashTableEntry *util = realloc(util, sizeof(HashTableEntry) * T->capacity);`, you haven't told the compiler what value to put in the `util` variable when it calls the `realloc` function, so you'll probably get undefined behavior, which is bad.

Comment: Huh?  No, look carefully at how you are calling malloc.  You are not passing `util` as an argument to `malloc`, so there is no issue.  When you call `realloc`, you are passing `util` as an argument, so it must be initialized first.

Comment: The arguments are the things you write inside the parentheses after a function name.  They are inputs to the function so you must decide what value they should have before you call the function.

Answer (score 3):

1. If the first argument is a null pointer, [`realloc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realloc.html) behaves like malloc() for the specified size.
2. If the first arg is an uninitialized pointer (bad pointer), [`realloc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realloc.html) won't work properly, so it returns NULL.
3. If the first arg is a valid address, [`realloc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realloc.html) 
   deallocates the old object and returns a pointer to a new object or it expands the memory of the old object (it's up to the OS to decide).

Answer (score 1):

As it is seen from the function call

```
HashTableEntry *util = realloc(util, sizeof(HashTableEntry) * T->capacity);
```

the function `realloc` uses argument `util`. If it has an indeterminate value then the function has undefined behavior.

Also before using any function you should read its description and the purpose of each its parameter.

From the C Standard (7.22.3.5 The realloc function)

> 2 The realloc function **deallocates the old object pointed to by
>   ptr** and returns a pointer to a new object that has the size
>   specified by size....

and

> 3 If ptr is a null pointer, the realloc function behaves like the
>   malloc function for the specified size.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra to expend memory the function must know the address of the memory  to expand. I wrote already if the first argument has indeterminate value then the function has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case `util` is uninitialised when passed into `realloc()`.
So the behaviour of `realloc()` is undefined.

```
HashTableEntry *util = realloc(util, sizeof(HashTableEntry) * T->capacity);
                             //^^^^ This value is undefined.
```

In the third case you initialise it to `NULL` in which case `realloc()` behaves like `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

Some items to note:

When calling `realloc()` do NOT assign directly into the target pointer.  Rather assign to a temporary pointer, then check (!=NULL) before assigning to the target pointer.

Then, if/when `realloc()` fails, the original pointer will not be lost.  Losing such a pointer results in a memory leak.

Note: the first parameter of `realloc()` is a 'source' pointer.  It must be pointing to something meaningful, like `NULL` or a known place in the heap.